# Java Validation: Validate an object within an object

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I have two objects:

```
public class CancelRequest{
 @NotEmpty
 private String id;

 @NotNull
 private BookingDetails;
}
```

BookingDetails object:

```
public class BookingDetails{
 @NotEmpty
 private String bookingId;
}
```

My class that is responsible for validating the request is `CancelRequestValidator`

```
...
import javax.validation.Validator;
...
public class CancelRequestValidator{
...
public void check(CancelRequest request){
 Set<ConstraintViolation<NorthAmericaCancelTripRequest>> violations = 
validator.validate(request);
...
 }
}
```

how I am performing validation?

```
CancelRequest request = new CancelRequest("id",new BookingDetails(""));
CancelValidator validator = new CancelValidator();
violations = validator.check(request);
```

The violation should have one entry in it saying bookingId cannot be empty but instead it thinks that the object valid. I need to do the validation this way because I have some other business validation that I need to perform on this object hence I am using a mixture of javax and custom validation.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform nested bean validation, you need to use the `@Valid` annotation on the nested object:

```
public class CancelRequest{
  @NotEmpty
  private String id;

  @NotNull
  @Valid
  private BookingDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eamon Scullion said, @Valid will work for nested validations, dont forget though to use @NotNull for Objects like Date, @NotBlank for text fields, and @NotEmpty for Iterable objects

```
public class CancelRequest{
    @NotBlank
    private String id;
    

    @NotEmpty
    private List<E> myList;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private BookingDetails;
}
```